# JPA persistence.xml properties in glassfish JDBC Resource

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, glassfish, eclipselink

I have an application running on Glassfish 4.1 that uses a JDBC Resource. In the application itself I have a `persistence.xml` file that lists all the entities and tells the container which JDBC Resource to use. I have defined some properties to log the SQL it executes. It looks something like this:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MyResource_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/my_resource</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.example.entities.EntityOne</class>
        <class>com.example.entities.EntityTwo</class>
        <class>com.example.entities.EntityThree</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Now when this application goes to production, I don't want the SQL to be logged. So every time I do a release, I need to remind myself to change the `eclipselink.logging` properties.

I thought, there should be a better way to handle this. So I went to the Glassfish admin console, to JDBC Resources and added the 2 properties there, but that doesn't work.

Is there any way to remove the "environment specific" values out of the `persistence.xml` file and into the Glassfish configuration? I have googled for a while now, but don't seem to find the correct sollution. What I did find is that Hibernate has the option to specify a "configuration file", but I haven't found this for EclipseLink.

Answer (score 0):

We used maintain property files for each environment such as DEV,QA,PROD,UAT etc in different files and copy one of them during build.

```
Ant build

<property environment="env" /> 
                <!-- ***** COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS DEMOED HERE -->
                <property name="build_type" value= "${env.build_type}"/>

<copy todir="deploy">
    <fileset dir="src_dir"/>
    <globmapper from=${env.build_type}".persistence.xml" to="persistence.xml"/>
 </copy>
```

Run build like this

```
ant -Denv.build_type=PROD
```

This will copy PROD.persistence.xml to persistence.xml

```
ant -Denv.build_type=DEV
```

This will copy DEV.persistence.xml to persistence.xml

Comment: That could work, but then you have a environment-dependent ear file. That's something I want to avoid. Isn't there a way around it? (Btw, I use maven, but that's no problem)

Comment: With Spring Profile you could initiate entity manager beans depending upon the active profile that will refer to the persistence.xml like dev-persistence.xml, test-persisitence.xml, prod-persistence.xml of your environment. And you can set Active profile using web.xml. Mostly the web.xml won't change that much so you can keep the web.xml in your repository with the spring profile active property set for that enviornment.

Comment: Store values in environment variables and let your program read from there.

Answer (score 0):

As per [glassfish documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/gdpwu.html), persistence.xml settings are meant to take precedence over global settings, so I wouldn't recommend anything in a persistence.xml file that you would want to override later.

That said, EclipseLink server integration can make use of a server log, allowing external control over settings.  See [this](https://lairdnelson.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/making-eclipselink-logging-play-nice-with-glassfish-3-1-2-2/) for a description of setting logging properties in glassfish that should control the log file EclipseLink writes to.  Otherwise, you can define a different log mechanism in your peristence.xml file, such as log4J or a custom one that you can control how you wish as touched on [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging)